# SSIS foreach Loop does not stop while all the processes are done

Tags: ssis

I have a foreach loop in my SSIS package to read some JSON files into SQL tables. It breaks each JSON data file into 30 different tables. All the objects in the loop are SQL Script task editors in the linear position precedence constraint connected to the next one after success. My last step is to write the file name in a table to make sure all the job of this file is done. But when all the files are inserted into the tables and I check and all the file names are in the mentioned table, the foreach loop container is still running while not even a single record is added to all the tables. I don't know why it is still working. It takes some times several hours to finally finishes.
Do you guys have any idea?

How can I stop it to go to the next steps?

Thanks,

Comment: What does it do after the last file has been processed, only the loop is running and not the tasks inside it? Is it a foreach with file enumerator? If yes, maybe there are some additional files in the folder it's trying to process?

Comment: a screenshot of what you've built will be useful. How is your ForEach Loop configured? Could you have error handling in your script tasks that are squashing the errors being reported?

Comment: My problem is with large number of files. when I run this package for 500 files it takes 6 minutes to finish while for 4000 files it takes almost 15 hours!!!

Answer (score 0):

My problem is with large number of files. when I run this package for 500 files it takes 6 minutes to finish while for 4000 files it takes almost 15 hours!!